# Read/Write Strategy For Consistency Level

Tags: cassandra

Based on [Read Operation in Cassandra at Consistency level of Quorum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043208/read-operation-in-cassandra-at-consistency-level-of-quorum)

```
there are 3 ways to read data consistency:
a. WRITE ALL + READ OoNE
b. WRITE ONE + READ ALL
c. WRITE QUORUM + READ QUORUM
```

For a data, the write operation usually happens once, but read operations often happens.
But take care of the read consistency, is it possible to merge a and b ?
This is, WRITE ONE -> READ ONE -> if not found -> READ ALL.
Does the approach usually fulfill read/write operation happen once?
There is only read ALL at first time on a node which has no the data.

### So Is my understanding correct?

Wilian, thanks for exactly elaborating. I think I need to describe my use case, as bellow. I implemented a timeline uses can post to. And users can follow the interesting post. So notification will be sent to the followers.  For saving bandwidth, users write/read post at CL ONE. Eventually, users always can read the post after a while by read repair. Followers will receive the notification of comments added to post  if they listen the post. Here is my question. It must make sure followers can read the comments if notification were delivers to followers. So I am indented to use CL ONE to check if the comment was synced to the node queried. If no result, try CL ALL to synced the comment. So other followers query from the node don't bother to sync other nodes since the CL ALL was done before,which can save bandwidth and lower server overhead. So as for your final scenario, I don't care if the value is old or latest because the data was synced according to notifications. I need to ensure  users can get the comment if notification was delivered to followers.

Answer (score 12):

From [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25043599/2390644) to the linked question, Carlo Bertuccini wrote:

> What guarantees consistency is the following disequation
>
> `(WRITE CL + READ CL) > REPLICATION FACTOR`

The cases A, B, and C in this question appear to be referring to the three *minimum* ways of satisfying that disequation, as given in the same answer.

#### Case A

`WRITE ALL` will send the data to `all replicas`.  If your replication factor (RF) is three(3), then `WRITE ALL` writes three copies before reporting a successful write to the client.  But you can't possibly *see* that the write occurred until the next read of the same data key.  Minimally, `READ ONE` will read from a single one of the aforementioned replicas, and satisfies the necessary condition:  `WRITE(3) + READ(1) > RF(3)`

#### Case B

`WRITE ONE` will send the data to only a single replica.  In this case, the only way to get a *consistent read* is to read from *all* of them.  The coordinator node will get all of the answers, figure out which one is the most recent and then send a "hint" to the out-of-date replicas, informing them that there's a newer value.  The hint occurs asynchronously but only after the `READ ALL` occurs does it satisfy the necessary condition:  `WRITE(1) + READ(3) > RF(3)`

#### Case C

`QUORUM` operations must involve `FLOOR(RF / 2) + 1` replicas.  In our RF=3 example, that is `FLOOR(3 / 2) + 1 == 1 + 1 == 2`.  Again, consistency depends on both the reads and the writes.  In the simplest case, the read operation talks to exactly the same replicas that the write operation used, but that's never guaranteed.  In the general case, the coordinator node doing the read will talk to *at least one* of the replicas used by the write, so it will see the newer value.  In that case, much like the `READ ALL` case, the coordinator node will get all of the answers, figure out which one is the most recent and then send a "hint" to the out-of-date replicas.  Of course, this also satisfies the necessary condition:  `WRITE(2) + READ(2) > RF(3)`

So to the OP's question...

### Is it possible to "merge" cases A and B?

To ensure *consistency* it is only possible to "merge" if you mean `WRITE ALL + READ ALL` because you can always *increase* the number of readers or writers in the above cases.

However, `WRITE ONE + READ ONE` is not a good idea if you need to read *consistent* data, so my answer is: **no**.  Again, using that disequation and our example RF=3: `WRITE(1) + READ(1) > RF(3)` **does not hold**.  If you were to use this configuration, receiving an answer that there is *no value* **cannot be trusted** -- it simply means that the *one* replica contacted to do the read did not have a value.  But values might exist on one or more of the other replicas.

So from that logic, it might seem that doing a `READ ALL` on receiving a *no value* answer would solve the problem.  And it would for that use case, but there's another to consider: what if you get *some value* back from the `READ ALL`... **how do you know** that the value returned is "the latest" one?  That's what's meant when we want consistency.  If you care about reading the most recent write, then you need to satisfy the disequation.

### Regarding the use case of "timeline" notifications in the edited question

If my understanding of your described scenario is correct, these are the main points to your use case:

- Most (but not all?) timeline entries will be write-once (not modified later)
- Any such entry can be followed (there is a list of followers)
- Any such entry can be commented upon (there is a list of comments)
- Any comment on a timeline entry should trigger a notification to the list of followers for that timeline entry
- Trying to minimize cost (in this case, measured as bandwidth) for the "normal" case
- Willing to rely on the *anti-entropy* features built into Cassandra (e.g. read repair)

> I need to ensure users can get the comment if notification was delivered to followers.

Since most of your entries are write-once, and you care more about the *existence* of an entry and not necessarily the latest content for the entry, you might be able to get away with `WRITE ONE + READ ONE` with a fallback to `READ ALL` if you get no record for something that had *some other indication it should exist* (e.g. from a notification).  For the timeline entry content, it does not sound like *your case* depends on *consistency* of the user content of the timeline entries.

*If* you don't care about consistency, then this discussion is moot; read/write with whatever Consistency Level and let Cassandra's asynchronous replication and anti-entropy features do their work.  That said, though your goal is minimizing network traffic/cost, if your workload is *mostly reads* then the added cost of doing *writes* at CL `QUORUM` or `ALL` may not actually be that much.

You also said:

> Followers will receive the notification of comments added to post if they listen the post.

This statement implies that you care about about not only whether the **set of followers** *exists* but also its *contents* (which users are following).  You have not detailed how you are storing/tracking the followers, but *unless you ensure the consistency of this data* it is possible that one or more followers are *not* notified of a new comment because you retrieved an out-of-date version of the follower list.  Or, someone who "unfollowed" a post could still receive notifications for the same reason.

Cassandra is very flexible and allows each discrete read and write operation to use different consistency levels.  Take advantage of this and ensure strong consistency where it is needed and relax it where you are sure that "reading the latest write" is not important to your application's logic and function.

Comment: You took so much time to read my case and analized it detailedly. I learned from this so much and how to use appropriate CL by cases. Much appriciated.