# Apache Cassandra: Explicit Read/Write consistencies required?

Tags: database, cassandra, tombstone

My company is using Cassandra (2.1.8), running on debian servers.

Without setting a consistency on my queries/preparedStatements, I would sometimes get "null" back from a `"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE key = ?"`. After adding:

```
statementGet.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
```

I get an answer every time. But from the article below:
[Read/Write Strategy For Consistency Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965038/read-write-strategy-for-consistency-level)

> If you don't care about consistency, then this discussion is moot;
>   read/write with whatever Consistency Level and let Cassandra's
>   asynchronous replication and anti-entropy features do their work. That
>   said, though your goal is minimizing network traffic/cost, if your
>   workload is mostly reads then the added cost of doing writes at CL
>   QUORUM or ALL may not actually be that much.

it is said that my consistency levels do not matter, if I don't care about consistency. And I don't. It doesn't not matter much to me if the data is hours or days old. But I do care about getting data everytime.

What I need to know is: Do I need to put a consistency level on my Writes as well, to ensure that they are actually written, and that my Read will **always** retrieve a value, if I have previously written anything.

And what might that consistency level be, given the above criteria?

Comment: Which consistency level do you user for writing and reading? Do you read immediately after writing? I know this behavour from my Unit Tests, where I write and read a lot of records using consistencyl evel ONE for my reads and QUORUM for writes?