# Cassandra reads failing intermittently

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I am facing a puzzling issue where my cassandra reads didn't return a value for key 'K'. I have a key that was inserted into a column family almost 2 weeks back and when I queried for that key using CQLSH consecutively 8 times, 2 times it didn't return a value. 6 times it showed the results correctly. The replication factor for my keyspace is 3.

This key was written with a QUORUM consistency (Java Hector client). I am reading it using CQLSH, which has a default consistency of one. I have not been able to come up with any explanation for this till now. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are not respecting the consistency level disequation:

> (WRITE CL + READ CL) > REPLICATION FACTOR

With RF = 3 -> QUORUM = 2

So your disequation say

> ((WRITE CL) 2 + (READ CL) 1) > 3
>  2 + 1 > 3 = FALSE

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043208/read-operation-in-cassandra-at-consistency-level-of-quorum/25043599#25043599) you can find how to achieve consistency. However you might be interested in tuning your [read repair chance](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/configuration/storage_configuration#read-repair-chance)

Try to set CL quorum in CQLSH using the `CONSISTENCY` command

```
cqlsh> CONSISTENCY QUORUM;
```

And perform the read again

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: Hey @Carlo thanks for the information. But isn't consistency just for ensuring the freshness of data returned ? Even if I use a read consistency of ONE (I used QUORUM consistency for writes), it would return the data for this specific key from the closest replica that holds this key. I can understand that with weak consistency you might not get the latest value for this key. But how is it possible that I don't get data for this key at all ? I have been trying to reason out under what circumstances cassandra wouldn't return data for an existent key at all, even if it is there ?

Comment: If you have 3 node RF for key K, and you wrote it with CL=Quorum it means only 2 nodes wrote it before returning control to the client. If a read with CL=1 is performed and the first node to answer is the one missing K you won't have any result back -- to verify try to set the CL as I say in my edited answer