# consistency questions about query on Cassandra using cql

Tags: cassandra, cql

I did the exact same query on cassandra, but the result is different, I'm wondering why. The detail is following:

```
    cqlsh:keyspace > select info_map from a where seq_id = '123456' limit 2;
    (0 rows)
    .....
    (after about 1 minute)
    .....
    cqlsh:keyspace > select info_map from a where seq_id = '123456' limit 2;
    {............data detail........}
    (1 rows)
```

I can assure you that the data is not instant (the data is inserted into database about 1 month ago), and the number of hit recode is at most 1 (though I write limit 2 in my cql). And my cassandra has two datacenters.

Comment: What consistency level did you use? What is your replication factor? Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043208/read-operation-in-cassandra-at-consistency-level-of-quorum/25043599#25043599

Comment: Consistency level is ConsistencyLevel.ONE.  replication factor is 3 (5 nodes in a cluster).

Comment: I think you answered your own question.

Comment: I know there is possibility that in a short interval the data is not consistency in different replicas. But the record I queried is about one month ago, shouldn't it be synchronized in the cluster?

Comment: If you're using CL.ONE, you may receive answers from different nodes, thus having different requests. Also if you wrote your data with CL.ONE, but having RF=3 for the keyspace, Cassandra may use a 'hinted-handoff' data recovery, if it detects that your row is under-replicated.