# Why is R + W > N strong consistency in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

Datastax claims when `R + W > N`  read and write is strong consistency

```
R is the consistency level of read operations
W is the consistency level of write operations
N is the number of replicas
```

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutDataConsistency.html

How can that be true?

if N is 3, quorum is 2, that means 1 node can have stale data

if R = 3 W = 1 , 3 + 1 > 3 , if you update the stale node, the data will not be consistent?

For example

```
nodeA k1 -> v_new
nodeB k1 -> v_new
nodeC k1 -> v_old
```

If you update nodeC on `k1`

`UPDATE my_table SET my_count = my_count + 1 WHERE id = my_primary_key`

the end result will be `v_old + 1` not `v_new + 1`

Shouldn't strong consistency be

```
R > N / 2 + 1
W > N / 2 + 1
```

when you read, you read from at least N / 2 + 1 nodes, and return the latest value

when you write, you first read from at least N / 2 + 1 nodes, and update the latest value to quorom (R > N / 2 + 1 and W > N / 2 + 1)

Comment: I answered your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043208/read-operation-in-cassandra-at-consistency-level-of-quorum

Answer (score 0):

> if R = 3 W = 1 , 3 + 1 > 3 , if you update the stale node, the data will not be consistent?

First of all, a write operation at consistency level `ONE` still writes to all replicas. But it only waits to receive a *confirmation* of that write from one of the nodes.

Secondly, if you have a RF of 3 and you read at consistency level of 3, that's called reading at consistency level `ALL`. A nice, little-known feature of reading at `ALL`, is that it *forces* a read-repair operation. That is, as long as it's checking the value of all 3 replicas, it automatically streams the most-current value to any stale replicas.

So yes, in the case of R=3 and W=1, Cassandra is still very much a strong-consistent system.

Comment: if your write updates stale replica first, then strong consistency is not achieved? You have to wait for the replica that has the latest data to respond, not just wait for any replica to respond? Am i getting something wrong?

Comment: @olaf writes to all replicas are concurrent; Cassandra cannot be directed to write to a stale replica before a current replica.

Comment: thanks, I have a folllow up question, cassandra does not have leader , so how does each write knows that its stale? Is coordinator responsible for figuring out that information, doesn't that necessary mean that consistency level ONE waits for all confirmation ONLY if the node that confirm does not have stale data?

So subsequent write after failure with CL ONE would be like 
coordinator ask all nodes for latest data (CL ALL), coordinator figures out which node can be updated, and wait for only one of those node to confirm new write (CL ONE)?