# How can we understand the concept of replication factor in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

What is replication factor in cassandra and how does it affect single DC or multiple DC nodes ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587869/understand-cassandra-replication-factor-versus-consistency-level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cassandra stores replicas on multiple nodes to ensure reliability and fault tolerance. **The total number of replicas across the cluster is referred to as the replication factor**. A replication factor of 1 means that there is only one copy of each row on one node. A replication factor of 2 means two copies of each row, where each copy is on a different node. All replicas are equally important; there is no primary or master replica

**When creating keyspace, you need to specify the replication factor on each DC.**

Example Single DC with SimpleStrategy:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE Excelsior WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3 };
```

- Here we specify replication_factor 3 means, Each row will be placed on three different node.

Example Multi DC :

```
CREATE KEYSPACE Excalibur WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1' : 3, 'dc2' : 2};
```

- This example sets three replicas for a data center named dc1 and two replicas for a data center named dc2

Source : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeReplication_c.html

Comment: I would rephrase this part: "Here we specify replication_factor 3 means three copies of each row will be placed on different node." It makes it sound as if a copy from the responsible node will be placed 3 times on another node.